# IE7 Ext JS problem: Unspecified JS error on window.close()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, extjs

I am using Ext JS to make a popup window, here is the code:

```
function popupImage(term, imageNumber){

    if(currentPopupWindow!=null){
        currentPopupWindow.close();
    }

    currentPopupWindow = new Ext.Window({
                layout      : 'fit',
                closeAction :'hide',
                plain       : true,
                constrain   : true,
                width: 300,
                border: false,
                html: "Blah blah content"<span onclick=\"currentPopupWindow.close();\">cerrar</span>"
            });



    currentPopupWindow.show(false, function(){
        var el = Ext.get("termimage");
        currentPopupWindow.setWidth(el.getWidth(true)+150);
    });

    currentPopupWindow.anchorTo(Ext.get("dictionarycontainer"), "tl");
}
```

In firefox this works fine. In IE7 it works, but always produces a javascript error saying "unspecified error".

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

Removing the anchorTo line removes the error. I would still like to anchor to though so this isn't a great solution!

Comment: Does it give you a line number?

Comment: Line 4: Unspecified error

I got to the debugger, it highlights

"M=G.getBoundingClientRect()"

As the error. That would be in Ext JS, i didnt write that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, dumb as it is:

Have the same window creation, then instead of the calls to show and anchor to:

```
    currentPopupWindow.render(document.body);
    currentPopupWindow.alignTo(diccon, "tl", [40, 80]);

                currentPopupWindow.show(false, function() {
            var el = Ext.get(termim);
            currentPopupWindow.setWidth(el.getWidth(true)+150);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search tells me that you're not the only extJS user that is experiencing this. (See [here](http://extjs.net/forum/showthread.php?t=36498) and [here](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24481) and [here](https://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=121796) for three examples.) Best would be to post in their [forums](http://extjs.net/forum/) so they can either fix their bug or work around an IE7 bug, whichever is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it has something to do with it, not that I understand..

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/11/29/ie-6-7-unspecified-error-when-accessing-offsetparent-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

qui is right. The problem lies in anchorTo. Use alignTo and the exception goes away.
Sorry qui, tried to "up" your response but were not able to. I don't have any reputation.:)

Athele

Answer (score 0):

To your second question: Removing the anchorTo line removes the error. I would still like to anchor to though so this isn't a great solution!

Use alignTo and monitor scroll and mousewheel event and update the position accordingly and it is the same as anchorTo. That is the workaround I have found.

Athele

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

`shim: false`

to popup window parameter list.